# How to run a single aggregation function on pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy function that creates multiple new columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [i % 3 for i in range(10)],
    'a': np.random.rand(10),
    'b': np.random.rand(10)
})

def my_agg(x):
    x = x.values.reshape([x.shape[0] // 2,2])
    prod = x[:,0] * x[:,1]
    return [np.sum(prod), np.mean(prod)]

df.set_index('group').stack().groupby('group').apply(my_agg)
```

Producing as result

```
group
0     [0.3625660911145343, 0.09064152277863358]
1       [1.132618561193485, 0.3775395203978283]
2    [0.37300784663400804, 0.12433594887800269]
dtype: object
```

whereas I would like to have separate column for each column. Is there a neat way to do this in pandas, taking into account that:

- the multiple features generated ar more complex and computing them together is more efficient;
- the number of features is much greater than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert output to `list`s and then to `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
def my_agg(x):
    x = x.values.reshape([x.shape[0] // 2,2])
    return [np.sum(x[:,0] * x[:,1]), np.mean(x[:,0] * x[:,1])]

s = df.set_index('group').stack().groupby('group').apply(my_agg)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index, columns=['a','b'])
print (df1)
              a         b
group                    
0      2.210601  0.552650
1      0.335913  0.111971
2      1.696796  0.565599
```

Or you can return `Series` and then `unstack`, but it shoud be slowier:

```
def my_agg(x):
        x = x.values.reshape([x.shape[0] // 2,2])
        return pd.Series([np.sum(x[:,0] * x[:,1]), np.mean(x[:,0] * x[:,1])], index=['a','b'])

df1 = df.set_index('group').stack().groupby('group').apply(my_agg).unstack()
print (df1)
              a         b
group                    
0      0.391921  0.097980
1      0.417366  0.139122
2      0.788845  0.262948
```